# Match a number after a dash using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello I am trying to match a number following a dash using regex in javascript.

The sentence is as follows:

```
on agreeing to the resolution Agreed to by recorded vote: 238 - 182 (Roll no. 164).
```

I currently can select the number 238 using:

```
(?:\s-\s)[0-9]+
```

But I have not been able to find a solution for selecting 182.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: That appears to select " - 182", not 238.  Are you trying to get them both? To get them both:  (?:[0-9]+\s-\s)[0-9]+

Answer (score 0):

You can capture each into its own group and then do something with them like this

```
string = "on agreeing to the resolution Agreed to by recorded vote: 238 - 182 (Roll no. 164)."    
var regex = /(\d+)\s*\-\s*(\d+)/;

string.replace(regex, "$1 what is this doing here $2");
=> "on agreeing to the resolution Agreed to by recorded vote: 238 what is this doing here 182 (Roll no. 164)."
```

You can also remove them, add to them, etc...

```
string.replace(regex, "<strong>$1</strong> - <strong>$2</strong>");
=> "on agreeing to the resolution Agreed to by recorded vote: <strong>238</strong> - <strong>182</strong> (Roll no. 164)."
```

Hope this helps.